# Submariner “Discovering network details CIDR” did not complete

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, rancher

I am running subctl from a VM like below to join an EKS Cluster. Note: VM is not in EKC VPC, it is external. Unfortunately, it ran for more than a few hours with no luck.

```
ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-59 ~]$ subctl join --kubeconfig /home/ec2-user/.kube/config broker-info.subm
* broker-info.subm says broker is at: https://6E23D7565331B5BEE5DD851EEFF1E19E.gr7.ap-southeast-2.eks.amazonaws.com
? What is your cluster ID? d837265
X Sorry, your reply was invalid: Value is required
⠈⠁ Discovering network details CIDR for your cluster?
Error determining the service CIDR: interruptcluster?

subctl version: v0.6.1
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to join an external node to the existing EKS cluster is as below:

```
subctl join --kubeconfig /home/ec2-user/.kube/config broker-info.subm --clustercidr "192.168.0.0/16" --servicecidr="10.0.0.0/24
```

Where

```
clustercidr=EKS Cluster CIDR address
servicecdr=External node VPC CIDR address
```

You should see output like below:

```
 ✓ Discovering network details
 ✓ Validating Globalnet configurations
 ✓ Discovering multi cluster details
 ✓ Deploying the Submariner operator
 ✓ Created operator CRDs
 ✓ Created operator namespace: submariner-operator
 ✓ Created operator service account and role
 ✓ Created lighthouse CRDs
 ✓ Created lighthouse service account and role
 ✓ Created Lighthouse service accounts and roles
 ✓ Deployed the operator successfully
 ✓ Creating SA for cluster
 ✓ Deploying Submariner
 ✓ Submariner is up and running
```